# LocalConection between a AIR application and Flash Player application

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs4, flash-builder

I'm trying to connect a AS2(swf on Flash player using Flash CS4) and AS3(swf on AIR using Flash Builder 4), but I get an error when I send a command from the AIR app:

```
[StatusEvent type="status" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 code=null level="error"]
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I tried LocalConnection between as3 and as2 too with little luck. Then I found [SWFBridge](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html) classes by Grant Skinner, and they worked for me.